# Vert.x JVisualVM monitoring

Tags: vert.x, jvisualvm

I've implemented a REST API with Vert.x and I want to monitor its threads. I package the app as a fat-jar and I'm using JVisualVM and JProfiler for monitoring.

When I launch it from the IDE (Intellij) I can see everything, but when I launch it with `java -jar fatjar` I can only see memory consumption.

I enabled JMX from the application thinking JVisualVM uses JMX to get the metrix, but it didn't help.

What should I do to enable JVisualVM access to threads and CPU?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

With jvisualVM you should be able to see all vert.x threads, however you should be aware that Vert.x is a reactive framework so you will not see a thread being spawn for each request. One thread (per CPU core) will handle all load.

What are you trying to monitor exactly would be interesting to know since it could be that you're just looking on the wrong place...